# How can I use the index from a Twig for loop in the name of an object property?

Tags: for-loop, indexing, escaping, twig

I'm trying to use the index of a for loop in the property names of an object. Is this possible?

```
{% for i in 0..20 %}

    {% include 'template.twig' with {
        title: object.property_{{i}}_title,
        length: object.property_{{i}}_length,
        width: object.property_{{i}}_width
    } %}

{% endfor %}
```

This results in a Twig error. Is it possible to use the `i` index from the for loop in the name of an object property?

Comment: `title : attribute(object, 'property_'~i~'_title'),`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several ways:

Interpolation:

```
{%
    include 'template.twig' with {
        title: object["property_#{i}_title"],
        length: object["property_#{i}_length"],
        width: object["property_#{i}_width"]
    } 
%}
```

Concatenation:

```
{%
    include 'template.twig' with {
        title: object["property_"~i~"_title"],
        length: object["property_"~i~"_length"],
        width: object["property_"~i~"_width"]
    } 
%}
```

or the attribute function (/cc comment from @DarkBee):

```
{%
    include 'template.twig' with {
        title: attribute(object, 'property_'~i~'_title'),
        length: attribute(object, 'property_'~i~'_length"),
        width: attribute(object, 'property_'~i~'_width'),
    } 
%}
```

See [a live demo](http://twigfiddle.com/ganupb) on twigfiddle.

Comment: I'm trying to access the property of an object, not an array. The first two options didn't work for me, and I think that may be why. The `attribute()` method _did_ work for me though. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I just tried again, and you're right, array syntax doesnt work on objects. But all syntaxes are working on arrays anyway. My mistake :)